# Having an issue with text-align: right on input element with "value" attribute

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this happens on macOS only, but I have this strange input behavior you can observe in the example below:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right-aligned-input {
  text-align: right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container"> 

  <label>
    Right aligned input: 
    <input class="right-aligned-input" type="text" value="100" name="right-aligned-input">
  </label>

</div>
```

The problem is when I hover over the value inside the input it somewhat scrolls/moves, which ends up disturbing my horizontal scroll. How can I solve this while keep using the value attribute? It doesn't happen when I use other text-align variants like "center".

**Edit:** I meant when I try scrolling horizontally with my touchpad while the cursor is above the input value, horizontal scroll does not work.

**Second Edit:** Specs and screen capture

Browser: Chrome - v84.0.4147.135

OS: macOS/Mojave - 10.15.5

Tried on Safari, Firefox, Opera this only happens with Chrome (tried with disabled extensions also)

The surface area of this problem is really minimal, thought that I would easily get someone who tumbled upon this before, but it seems I'm wrong :(

Hopefully, someone can reproduce this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am unable to reproduce in Edge Version 86.0.608.2 (Official build) dev (64-bit) on Windows 10. Note that you've misspelled `label` in your opening tag.

Comment: Fixed. Yeah :( it seems like it's macOS/macbook specific problem... Thanks!

Comment: Do not have a Mac on hand, but I cannot reproduce on any browser in Windows.

Comment: unable to reproduce problem on a mac book.  voting to close

Comment: @DCR I will post gif once I'm home... I'm having this issue on both of my macbooks...

Comment: you need to provide more information.  What browser, what browser version, what os, what os version.  Also, make sure your snippet shows the problem on at least your machine

Comment: I will. It does.

Comment: @DCR Updated the description with system specs and added screen captures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be a bug with chromes default useragent style sheet adding `direction: rtl;` manually seems to fix it atleast for me. See reproduction below.

Note manually adding `rtl` makes the input harder to use, you are better off ignoring the issue.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right-aligned-input {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <label>
    Right aligned input: 
    <input class="right-aligned-input" type="text" value="100" name="right-aligned-input">
  </label>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh damn, it fixed it! Haven't heard of chromium's user-agent stylesheet before. Adam Argyle (working on Chrome) has good content about it, it seems. (Which is an interesting coincidence for me I was just listening to him on Syntax.fm this morning...lol)

Anyways, thanks a lot, that's awesome! :)

Comment: Yo y'all! Logged a bug around this! Find it here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1121668